# Double geometries in GML with different EPSG using GDAL

Tags: gdal, epsg, gml

In our GML we have two geometries (a British National Grid and a ETRS89) so to try and extract these we use a GFS file with the following additional XML to extract them.

```
<GeomPropertyDefn>
<Name>geom_bng</Name>
<ElementPath>position</ElementPath>
<Type>Point</Type>
</GeomPropertyDefn>
<GeomPropertyDefn>
<Name>geom_latlong</Name>
<ElementPath>positionLatLong</ElementPath>
<Type>Point</Type>
</GeomPropertyDefn>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abpr:AddressBaseSupplySet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:abpr="http://namespaces.geoplace.co.uk/addressbasepremium/2.1" xmlns:gmlxbt="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.3/xbt" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://namespaces.geoplace.co.uk/addressbasepremium/2.1 http://www.geoplace.co.uk/addressbase/schema/2.1/addressbasepremium.xsd" gml:id="FC1">
<gml:description>Ordnance Survey (c) Crown Copyright. All rights reserved, 2023 and produced by GeoPlace</gml:description>
<abpr:basicLandPropertyUnitMember>
<abpr:BasicLandPropertyUnit gml:id="uk.addressbase.uprn.100031706996">
<abpr:changeType>I</abpr:changeType>
<abpr:position>
<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" gml:id="uk.addressbase.uprn.p.100031706996">
<gml:pos>408151.00 314401.00</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</abpr:position>
<abpr:positionLatLong>
<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258" gml:id="uk.addressbase.uprn.pl.100031706996">
<gml:pos>52.7272101 -1.8807384</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</abpr:positionLatLong>
</abpr:BasicLandPropertyUnit>
</abpr:basicLandPropertyUnitMember>
</abpr:AddressBaseSupplySet>
```

However if I look at the ogrinfo of the file using that GFS template it can now extract both geometries but it thinks that both have the same EPSG, but they do not.

What do I need to add to the GFS file to tell them they are in fact two different geometries with two different EPSGs?

Comment: Please create and share a small test dataset. Use fake geometries and attributes if your data are confidential.

Comment: @user30184 add a sample record

Comment: There is an .xsd based test in the GDAL autotest suite. It is using this file https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/data/gml/multiple_geometry_fields_srs_detection.gml and the .xsd in the same directory. Maybe having a look at those files could help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two additional things to do:

1. Remove the SRS definition from the .gfs file

`<!--<SRSName>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258</SRSName>-->`

2. Force GDAL to read the SRS from the data by adding an open option

`-oo FORCE_SRS_DETECTION=YES`

Test that the two geometries report different spatial reference systems:

```
ogrinfo 2geom.gml -al -oo FORCE_SRS_DETECTION=YES
INFO: Open of `2geom.gml'
      using driver `GML' successful.
Metadata:
  DESCRIPTION=Ordnance Survey (c) Crown Copyright. All rights reserved, 2023 and produced by GeoPlace

Layer name: BasicLandPropertyUnit
Geometry (geom_bng): Point
Geometry (geom_latlong): Point
Feature Count: 1
Extent (geom_bng): (-1.880740, 52.727210) - (408151.000000, 314401.000000)
Extent (geom_latlong): (-1.880738, 52.727210) - (-1.880738, 52.727210)
SRS WKT (geom_bng):
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",
....
SRS WKT (geom_latlong):
GEOGCRS["ETRS89",
    ENSEMBLE["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble",
```

The "Extent (geom_bng): (-1.880740, 52.727210) - (408151.000000, 314401.000000)" has obviously wrong minimum values. I do not know if it makes harm for further processing.